# Can a Tkinter button have children?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have the following code to create a button in Tkinter:

```
button = Button(self.parent_frame, width=100, height=100)
frame = Frame(button)
label = Label(frame, text="This is a button")
frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

When I hover my mouse over some parts of the button, the button rapidly resizes to the width of the window and then back to its initial size. Why does this happen? Is a Tkinter button not allowed to have children?

**Note:** I am not planning on using a frame inside a button, I am just asking this for hypothetical purposes. So instead of answers suggesting workarounds, I would prefer explanations as to why this happens.

Comment: is this a tkinter button or a ttk button? Also, what platform are you seeing this on? technically speaking a button can have children, though that may not work on OSX, and it may not work with ttk buttons.

Comment: It's a Tkinter button, and I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Check out this discussion thread: https://mail.python.org/pipermail//tkinter-discuss/2012-May/003141.html

Comment: Doesnt really have an answer I beleive but some of the comments might be helpfull into getting some insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, yes, a button can have children. I suspect the behavior is undefined for platforms that use native widgets (ie: OSX and Windows).